# sent mail succed on my machine but failed the server using phpmailer

Tags: email, phpmailer, php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = "gdssdh";
//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "myemail@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "******";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('mysent@gmail.com', 'PRSPS');

//$mail->AddReplyTo("user2@gmail.com', 'First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PRSPS password";

//$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "mymail@yahoo.co.in";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "user2");

//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

**When I run the script on my local machine I got**

> CLIENT -> SMTP: EHLO localhost CLIENT -> SMTP: AUTH LOGIN CLIENT ->
>   SMTP: cHV0aGVhLmh1b25nMjAxNEBnbWFpbC5jb20= CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   UHV0aGVhMDEy CLIENT -> SMTP: MAIL FROM: CLIENT -> SMTP: RCPT TO:
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: DATA CLIENT -> SMTP: Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 04:25:49
>   -0400 CLIENT -> SMTP: Return-Path: CLIENT -> SMTP: To: user2 CLIENT -> SMTP: From: PRSPS CLIENT -> SMTP: Subject: PRSPS password CLIENT ->
>   SMTP: Message-ID: <405be3508111cd4789653ec34cdfba23@localhost> CLIENT
>   -> SMTP: X-Priority: 3 CLIENT -> SMTP: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.6 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   MIME-Version: 1.0 CLIENT -> SMTP: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: boundary="b1_405be3508111cd4789653ec34cdfba23" CLIENT
>   -> SMTP: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: --b1_405be3508111cd4789653ec34cdfba23 CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: gdssdh
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   --b1_405be3508111cd4789653ec34cdfba23 CLIENT -> SMTP: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: gdssdh
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   --b1_405be3508111cd4789653ec34cdfba23-- CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: . CLIENT -> SMTP: quit Message sent!

**But When I run the same script on hosting**

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. (10060)SMTP Connect() failed. Mailer
>   Error: SMTP Connect() failed.

Do you have any idea to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a firewall preventing access to port 465?
Can you telnet in to 465 on smtp.google.com?

Comment: How can we check it on the hosting?

Comment: If you have server access to the hosting (SSL access) you can use a terminal or Putty to access the server, then test a telnet connection from it. Some hosts also has firewall settings in the admin pages for the account.

Comment: Do you have some tips for testing telnet connection ? what it can or can not ? thanks

Comment: I guess the answer depends on if you have SSL terminal access to the host account or not. If you have, you should be able to run the command "telnet smtp.google.com 465" without errors.

Comment: Now I am contacting the hoster,I will let you know after I have permission ,thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosting may have firewalled the used ports. Try using other ports (with other security) settings or contact your hoster.

Comment: Is it really possible to access smtp.gmail.com using other non standard ports?

Comment: Quoting from just any Googled hit http://cavewall.jaguardesignstudio.com/2011/10/12/google-apps-smtp-without-ssl-part-1/ : *That’s a problem, as Google Apps email accounts use smtp.gmail.com on port 465 (for SSL) or **587** (for TLS). Unencrypted sending is not possible through this SMTP server.*

Comment: Also another quote from there, for non-secured connections: *http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176600 The answer is to replace the smtp.gmail.com settings with:

    server: **aspmx.l.google.com**
    port: 25*