# PHPMailer doesn't seeem to work on live site, but works on localhost?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a PHPMailer script, and I've checked all the other threads that are similar to this, and tried all the solutions that follow the question. But here's the error I'm receiving

```
2014-01-03 02:25:16 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

And here's my script:

```
$body = "test";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // I have also tried tls
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;            
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // I have also tried 25
$mail->Username   = "xxxx@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "xxxxx";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom("johndoe@gmail.com","John  Doe");

$mail->AddReplyTo("johndoe@gmail.com","John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "Booking from " . $_POST['person'] . ' at ' . $_POST['name'];

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test


$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "johndoe@hotmail.co.uk";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

However I just cannot get it to work. I've tried to many different solutions. I'm even happy to use the default php mail however I just need it to send, the php mail wouldn't even get past the hotmail spam filters (by that I mean it didn't even send it to spam).

Any solutions or suggestions here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you ruled out simple firewall issues?  When it works locally but not remotely, you're probably writing about blocked ports. You can check for blocked port with fsockopen, a-la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226374/test-if-port-open-and-forwarded-using-php

Comment: Have you tried port 587 (for TLS)?

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me a lifetime of hassle! +1!

Comment: Are you referring to what I said about port 587? @Jarrod just by curiousity.

Comment: Yeah I was, that worked great :)

Comment: I had found an answer here on SO containing that in a comment in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17144196/1415724 which is why I mentioned it, hoping it would fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just comment this line:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your php.ini mail settings are the same on both your live server and your localhost server?

Comment: I think this should be a comment on the main question rather than an 'answer'. However no, I do not have access to the live server php.ini settings.

Comment: It's a rough start when you can't make a comment because you only have enough reputation to leave an answer. Let this be a lesson, if you're going to answer, provide a solution, not inquire further or ask questions about the scenario. +1 for now to even this out.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried to leave a comment, but got an error saying I didn't have enough reputation, whatever that means...  Don't seem to have any problems commenting on my own post, however..

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP Mailer From

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

And Read "A Simple Example"

```
<?php
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); // Load your PHPMailerAutoload.php Correctly Here

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;// debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'yourmail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '**********';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;           // or 587                         // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('fromemail@gmail.com', 'Vijay Rami');
$mail->addAddress('toemail@gmail.com', 'Vijay Rami');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
//$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```